# Dibujar en pantalla varios actores de la misma clasee (LibGDX JAVA)

Tags: java, libgdx

Al crear diferentes actores de la misma clase cada uno con una posición distinta al ejectuar el programa solo crea el último actor creado.

[image: Resultado el codigo]

```
public class MyGdxAjedrez extends ApplicationAdapter {

private SpriteBatch lienzo;
private ShapeRenderer shaper1;
private ShapeRenderer shaper2;
private Stage stage;

private Torre torreBlanco;
private Caballo caballoBlanco;
private Alfil alfilBlanco;
private Rey reyBlanco;
private Reina reinaBlanco;
private AlfilDer alfilBlancoDer;
private CaballoDer caballoBlancoDer;
private TorreDer torreBlancaDer;


private ArrayList<Peon> peones;

private OrthographicCamera cam;
private int ancho;
private int alto;

@Override
public void create() {

    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    Torre torreBlanco = new Torre(0, 0);
    Caballo caballoBlanco = new Caballo(50, 0);
    Alfil alfilBlanco = new Alfil(100, 0);
    Rey reyBlanco = new Rey(150, 0);
    Reina reinaBlanco = new Reina(200, 0);
    AlfilDer alfilBlancoDer = new AlfilDer(250, 0);
    CaballoDer caballoBlancoDer = new CaballoDer(300, 0);
    TorreDer torreBlancaDer = new TorreDer(350, 0);

    Peon peon1 = new Peon(0, 50);
    Peon peon2 = new Peon(100, 50);
    Peon peon3 = new Peon(150, 50);
    Peon peon4 = new Peon(200, 50);
    Peon peon5 = new Peon(250, 50);
    Peon peon6 = new Peon(300, 50);
    Peon peon7 = new Peon(350, 50);


    peones = new ArrayList();

    stage.addActor(torreBlanco);
    stage.addActor(caballoBlanco);
    stage.addActor(alfilBlanco);
    stage.addActor(reyBlanco);
    stage.addActor(reinaBlanco);
    stage.addActor(alfilBlancoDer);
    stage.addActor(caballoBlancoDer);
    stage.addActor(torreBlancaDer);
    stage.addActor(peon1);
    stage.addActor(peon2);
    stage.addActor(peon3);
    stage.addActor(peon4);
    stage.addActor(peon5);
    stage.addActor(peon6);
    stage.addActor(peon7);
```

Añado tambien una captura de la clase peon

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo de la imagen:

package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable;

```
public class Peon extends Actor implements InputProcessor {

    private static Texture textura = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Peon.png"));
    private static Sprite sprite = new Sprite(textura);
    private float posX;
    private float posY;

    public Peon(float posX, float posY) {
        sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);
        setBounds(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());
        setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    }

    public void draw(Batch lienzo, float parentAlpha) {
        sprite.draw(lienzo);
    }
```

Comment: Con que pusieras la clase de `Peon` bastaba para saber que tenia mal, No pusiste la clase de `Peon` pero estoy seguro que el problema es que estas usando la misma referencia para su imagen, `new Peon()` no exige ningun tipo de referencia de imagen imagino que la tienes `static`, si no has resolvido este problema, puede porfavor poner la clase de `Peon`?

Comment: Era exactamente lo que decias, muchas gracias de verdad @centenond